# How to make MediaPlayer and MediaRecorder run at the same time?

Tags: android, kotlin, audio

There are already several questions on this topic, but I couldn't get the answer that I want.

So, I would try to provide my minimal test case here, in that case it might help others in the future.

[image]

The basic UI look as above, to reproduce the test case, firstly, we should put a MP3 file into local directory, named it as `recording1.mp3`.

Then click the **PLAY** button to play the `recording1.mp3`, when the mp3 is playing, click **START** button to start recording and click **STOP** to finish recording.

The core logic would looks like:

```kotlin
        button_start_recording.setOnClickListener {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
            ...
            } else {
                mediaRecorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                mediaRecorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
                mediaRecorder?.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
                mediaRecorder?.setOutputFile(output)
                startRecording()
            }
        }

    private fun startRecording() {
        try {
            mediaRecorder?.prepare()
            mediaRecorder?.start()
            state = true
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun startPlaying() {
        try {
            thread {
                val playSource =
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/recording1.mp3"
                mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(playSource)
                mediaPlayer?.prepare()
                mediaPlayer?.start()
            }
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

I wanna get the record that would mix the background music as the `recording1.mp3` was playing and the audio was recorded. But what I got was only the `recording1.mp3` sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I Think**,change your `mediaRecorder?.setoutFormat` to

```
mediaRecorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_2_TS)
```

**Or**

```
mediaRecorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
```

prepare your MediaPlayer `mediaPlayer?.prepare()` before starting of your recording

And, play your Background music (with volume as you want) and start the recorder .

May it Works. Thanks!

Comment: Though there's noice from the background music and the voice from the `MIC` is much clear, your solution works!

Comment: Congratulations,and Best of Luck!